# python debugging, and finding out where variables get set

Tags: python, debugging, wikipedia

I'm working on modding the wikipedia python module, that's located here: 
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wikipedia/

Effectively, I'd like to be able to point it at a different wikimedia based site that also supports the same API calls (which is pretty common).

there is a global variable defined in wikipedia.py in that package, that's later updated for language domain, you can see the details here:

https://github.com/goldsmith/Wikipedia/blob/master/wikipedia/wikipedia.py

Here's the interesting part:

If I modify wikipedia.py (that I pip installed into site-packages) to completely change the API_URL, somehow it still is getting set to the old value.

Using pdb to step through the code, it happens right after the regular expression import, which makes me think the new code isn't 'sticking' or taking place. I've tried deleting the compiled python pyc files, to no avail.

As soon as I start up python in interactive mode, import wikipedia, and look at the value of API_URL it's not what I set it to. I must be missing something obvious, and it's bugging me.

```
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:28:03) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import wikipedia
>>> wikipedia.API_URL
u'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php'
```

Here are some other bits that I don't understand.

is it necessary to include the 'u' as part of the string?  why does setting the variable at runtime not work for either case (including the u or not). I realize the u is denoting unicode, but I'm not sure if it should be set or not when I manually set the variable, or if it's even required.

```
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:28:03) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import wikipedia
>>> wikipedia.API_URL
u'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php'
>>> wikipedia.API_URL = 'http://example.com/w/api.php'
>>> wikipedia.search("Barack")
[u'Barak (given name)', u'Barack Obama', u'Inauguration of Barack Obama', u'First inauguration of Barack Obama', u'Nationwide opinion polling for the United States presidential election, 2012', u'Barack Obama Presidential Center', u'Political positions of Barack Obama', u'Barack (disambiguation)', u'Statewide opinion polling for the United States presidential election, 2008', u'Barack Obama presidential campaign endorsements']
>>> wikipedia.API_URL = u'http://example.com/w/api.php'
>>> wikipedia.search("Barack")
[u'Barak (given name)', u'Barack Obama', u'Inauguration of Barack Obama', u'First inauguration of Barack Obama', u'Nationwide opinion polling for the United States presidential election, 2012', u'Barack Obama Presidential Center', u'Political positions of Barack Obama', u'Barack (disambiguation)', u'Statewide opinion polling for the United States presidential election, 2008', u'Barack Obama presidential campaign endorsements']
```

edit: oh man, this is embarassing. I forgot I had downloaded the package initially from github, and THAT version was actually being imported by default since it was located in the same directory as the project I'm working on. Yikes.

the print wikipedia.**file** was showing a relative path that I had assumed was in the site-packages directory. Wrong assumption!

Comment: Are you sure you edit the right file? Execute in REPL `print wikipedia.__file__`

Comment: I've never used REPL, let me do some reading and see if I can understand - I'm not sure how REPL is different from the interactive shell

Comment: the print statement you refer to simply shows the __init__.py as expected, and that file only imports the wikipedia and exceptions modules, you can see it here: https://github.com/goldsmith/Wikipedia/blob/master/wikipedia/__init__.py

Comment: most likely you edited wrong file, so I've asked you to check if `print wikipedia.__file__` outputs path to the files you actually edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `print wikipedia.__file__` gives you the file name that you're looking for, why don't you just set the `API_URL` after importing?

```
import wikipedia
wikipedia.API_URL = "http://de.wikipedia.org/w/api.php"
```

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention, because I found this so obvious: search for `API_URL` in wikipedia.py and other files. You'll notice it is set in `set_lang()`, so everything calling that will override your manual setting. you might just want to use `set_lang(your_domain)`!

Comment: Also, I'm not trying to dynamically change the language domain while hitting hte main wiki site, I'm trying to use other mediawiki based sites, which should work in theory. I've modified both the variable in set_lang as well as the original variable setting that's under the regex import call in the beginning of the script.

Comment: FWIW, this is actually the first thing I tried. But it doesn't stick. I only have one wikipedia.py, and I've grepped through my entire python directory to find code excerpts in there that could change the API_URL to no avail. The _only_ place where API_URL is set, is within wikipedia.py. I realize this seems like a really basic question, that's what's driving me nuts at the moment. I feel like I'm missing something basic here.

Comment: then something magical is happening `</sarcasm>`. I'm pretty optimistic that you're not loading the right module. Have you quit and restarted your `python` process, or at least did a `reload(wikipedia)`?

Comment: yes, I've restarted the python shell many times. I just tried reloading wikipedia at runtime, with no help either - you're right it completely stinks of me editing the wrong file. let me see if I can find a good way to show the path of the module being loaded once in the shell. from the python root, i searched for all possible wikipedia modules, but it again only shows the one file - see here http://pastie.org/10226930

Comment: @tony: read my answer?! That's the way to show the path to the module being used...

Comment: @tony: `path_to_module = module.__file__`

Comment: you're right marcus, it finally sunk in what is going on. module.__file__ is printing a relative path, not an absolute path, and there was another copy of wikipedia.py that I had forgotten about and downloaded.